# struts checkbox : deselect and submit

Tags: html, struts

In my JSP page I have:

```
<nested:checkbox property="product.hasEmployee" />
```

This checkbox is selected by default, when I deselect it then 
I submit the page, I find it selected !

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: How do you have it "selected by default"? Is that in your `Form` object or in the `Controller`? Having more code around this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this code in the server side:

```
if (request.getParameter("product.hasEmployee") == null) {
     product.setHasEmployee(false);
}
```